# Volume of an igloo

Tags: algebra-precalculus

AN igloo is a hemispherical structure built of blocks of ice by the Eskimos. THe interior diameter of the floor of an igloo is 6.

Explain whether an Eskimo who is 1.7m tall could stand up straight inside the igloo.

This is what I have tried:

```
                                        x*3^2*pi=1.7m
```

I worked this out only to find out that 1.7m is not the height but the volume.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain how to do this question.

thanks

Comment: It would more interesting if the interior *area* (and not diameter) of the floor is $6$. In this case he would not be able to stand up straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diameter is $6m$ therefore the radius is $3m$ which is also the height of the hemisphere. $1.7m<3m$ therefore he can stand up.

Comment: I over thought it haha